# Почему потоки не блокирую друг друга?

Tags: java, многопоточность

```
public class TH {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Thread t1 = new Thread(new T1());
    t1.start();
  } 
}

class T1 extends Thread{
  public void run(){
    Thread t= new Thread(new T2(this));
    t.start();
    try {
      t.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
class T2 extends Thread{
  private T1 t1;
  T2(T1 t1) {
    this.t1=t1;
  }

  public T2(){};

  public void run(){
    try {
      t1.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }   
  }
}
```

Я так понимаю ссылка на объект Т1 в классе Т2 содержит не экземпляр объекта на котором вызван поток

Comment: Опишите, какой эффект вы ожидаете, и что происходит на самом деле.

Comment: Обратите внимание, что вы _не запускаете_ поток (`new T1()`), созданный в `main`. Вы запускаете _другой_ поток (`new Thread(...)`), который запускает в себе `T1.run()`.

Answer (score 1):

Если Вы пытаетесь словить дедлок, то так:

```
package main;

public class SimpleDeadlockTest {

    public SimpleDeadlockTest() {
        _res1 = new SomeResource();
        _res2 = new SomeResource();
        new TH1();
        new TH2();
    }

    private class SomeResource {}

    private SomeResource _res1, _res2;

    private class TH1 extends Thread {
        public TH1() {
            start();
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            synchronized (_res1) {
                System.out.println("TH1 ACCESSED RES1.");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                synchronized (_res2) {
                    System.out.println("TH1 ACCESSED RES2.");
                }
            }
            System.out.println("TH1 STOPPED");
        }
    }

    private class TH2 extends Thread {
        public TH2() {
            start();
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            synchronized (_res2) {
                System.out.println("TH2 ACCESSED RES2.");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                synchronized (_res1) {
                    System.out.println("TH2 ACCESSED RES1.");
                }
            }
            System.out.println("TH2 STOPPED");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SimpleDeadlockTest();
    }

}
```

Если нужен не дедлок - то опишите то, чего Вы хотите добиться.

Comment: Кстати, если нужен проверенный класс, который обнаруживает дедлоки - могу показать.